# Conservative formulation for compact finite difference schemes

Tags: finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, banded-matrix

At the Section 4.2 of [this](http://acoustics.ae.illinois.edu/pdfs/lele-1992.pdf) paper (which is very well known in the computational fluid dynamic community), the author claims that it is enough, for the **compact finite difference** formulation in eq. 4.2.3 (as applied to problem 4.2.1) to be conservative, that the matrix $B$ (note, the derivation matrix is $A^{-1}B$) have all columns but first and last which sum to zero, but gives no proof or reference for this.

Well I can't get this obvious proof.

I've searched on the web for other papers (citing or not this one) and found some [results](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999112005712) (see Section 2.1 and Appendix A) and proofs for cases which are much simpler.

**EDIT**

The author first considers the model equation

$$\partial_t f + \partial_x F = 0, \quad x \in [a,b] \subseteq \mathbb R, t \in \mathbb R^+$$

for the quantity $f(x,t)$, which has flux $F(x,t) = \hat{F}(f(x,t))$. By integrating over $[a,b]$, it is shown that $f$ is conserved, in that the total $f$ in the domain $[a,b]$ changes in time only due to the flux $F$ at the boundaries.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int^b_a f(x,t) dx = - (F(b,t) - F(a,t))\tag{1}\label{integral}$$

(All this is clear to me so far.)

At this point the author seeks a discrete analog for Eq. \eqref{integral}.

**What I would do is the following.**

To keep it simple and get the basic idea, I would consider a linear version of the model equation, *i.e.* the linear advection equation with $F = f$,
$$\partial_t f + \partial_x f = 0$$
then I would discretize it in space,

$$ \frac{\text d}{\text dt} \textbf f + \textbf D \textbf f = 0 \tag{2}\label{discretized}$$

where $\textbf f$ contains nodal values of $f$ and $\textbf D$ is a derivation matrix. A reasonable discrete analog for the integral $\int^b_a f(x,t) dx$ is, in my opinion, the sum of all nodal values of $\textbf f$, *i.e.* $\textbf 1^{\text T} \textbf f$, being $\textbf 1$ the unitary column, so I'd multiply Eq. \eqref{discretized} by $\textbf 1^{\text T}$ (and take it in the time derivative), obtaining

$$\frac{\text d}{\text dt} \textbf 1^{\text T} \textbf f = - \textbf 1^{\text T}\textbf D \textbf f \tag{3}\label{guilty}$$

At this point I'd conclude that, for the LHS of Eq. \eqref{guilty} to depend only on first and last elements of $\textbf f$ in the way as Eq. \eqref{integral}, the row vector $\textbf 1^{\text T}\textbf D$ should be $(-1,0,0,\dots,0,0,1)$, *i.e.* all columns of $\mathbf D$ should sum up to zero, except the first and last (which should sum up to $-1$ and $1$ respectively).

**Turning point**

The paper in question is about compact finite difference schemes, in which case the matrix $\mathbf D$ can be written as $\mathbf A^{-1} \mathbf B$.

The author claims that

> In order to satisfy the global conservation constraint it is
>   sufficient to require that the columns $2$ through $N-1$ of the matrix
>   $\mathbf B$ sum exactly to zero. **This ensures that only the boundary
>   nodes contribute to the boundary fluxes**.

which is clearly not consistent with what I wrote just after Eq. \eqref{guilty}.

So either the author is wrong (unlikely, since the paper has been cited more than five thousands times since 1992), or I misunderstood what he means by *global conservation constraint* as applied to the space-discrete equation or, in other words, multiplying Eq. \eqref{discretized} by $\mathbf 1^\text{T}$ is not the intended discrete analog of integrating $f$ over the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix $\mathbf B$ having columns summing up to $(-1,0,0,...,0,0,+1)$ does not imply that the same happens for $\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B$.

Indeed, **if** $\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf B$ has that property, than it is correct to use $\mathbf 1^{\text{T}}$ to discretize the integral over the domain. If the scheme used is such that $\mathbf B$ has that property, than the row vector $\textbf 1^{\text{T}} \textbf A$ should be used to discretize the integral.

This appears clearer in the light of R. Knikker's 2009 paper on the Journal of Computational Physics.

Answer (score 1):

The equation:
$$\partial_t f + \partial_xF = 0$$  with $f_{x=0} = f_0(t)$ (which is known) and appropiate initial conditions can be discretised as follows:
$$\partial_t\vec{f}+D\vec{F}=\vec{b}\tag{*}$$
Where $\vec{f} = (f_1,f_2,...,f_{N+1})^T$ and $D$ is the discrete operator which replaces $\partial_x$, and is equal to:
$$D = \frac{1}{h}\left[\begin{matrix}1 &  &  & &\\
                          -1 &1&&&\\
                             & -1&1&&\\
                             &   &-1&1&&\\
                             &   &  & \ddots& \ddots
\end{matrix}\right] $$
and $\vec{b} = (F(f_0(t))/h,0,...,0)^T$ the boundary condition (inflow at first node).

Conservation implies that if we sum all fluxes of equation $(*)$ multiplying by a vector $\vec{1}=(1,1,...)$ we must obtain the total variation of fluxes $f_T = \sum_if_i$ 
$$\partial_t f_T+\vec{1}^TD\vec{F}=F(f_0(t))/h$$
since $\vec{1}^TD = (0,0,...,1)$
$$\partial_t f_T = F(f_0(t))/h-\vec{F}(L)/h$$
which is the conservation requirement.

Since this applies for both cases, in which node $0$ or $N+1$ are inflow boundaries (matrix $D$ changes accordingly) we can say that all the sum of all the columns must add to $0$, as shown ($\vec{1}^TD$ must be equal to $(1,0,0,...)$ or $(0,0,....,1)$ if the inflow is at the last or first node respectively).

Comment: I follow your reasoning, but it's not clear to me to what extent it is true that this property (zero sum of columns) of the $D = A^{-1}B$ matrix is implied by the matrix $B$ having that property.